# What do square brackets mean after a dict variable

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

I just wanted to know what does the square bracket mean in `check[]` and what does this square bracket do, because all I know that `{}` are dictionaries and `[]` are lists.

```
n = int(input().strip())
check = {True: "Not Weird", False: "Weird"}

print(check[
    n%2==0 and (
        n in range(2,6) or 
        n > 20)
])
```

Comment: You're accessing the dictionary's value by key. If this code doesn't need to support Python < 2.5, there are better options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator

Answer (score 2):

`check` is a dictionary and `check[k]` looks up the key `k` in this dictionary and returns the associated value.

This is a "clever" way of writing:

```
n = int(input().strip())

if n%2==0 and (n in range(2,6) or n > 20):
    print("Not Weird")
else:
    print("Weird")
```