# in the below program, i don't understand how was the data stored from the list into the count_dict

Tags: python, database, dataframe, list, dictionary

```
sample_list = [11, 45, 8, 11, 23, 45, 23, 45, 89]
print("Original list ", sample_list)

count_dict = dict()
for item in sample_list:
    if item in count_dict:
        count_dict[item] += 1 # how was the data stored into the variable count_dict?
    else:
        count_dict[item] = 1

print("Printing count of each item  ", count_dict)
```

i just don't understand how the program works

Comment: [What do square brackets mean after a dict variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153174/what-do-square-brackets-mean-after-a-dict-variable) Is that what you are asking?

Comment: You were able to add to the value because when the key did not exist you explicitly set the value to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If number not in dict then program create key (`number`) with value `1`. If same number appears in loop again and dict already have this key then value of this key increases by `1`.

In result there would be `count_dict` where keys are numbers from `sample_list` and values are count of key in `sample_list`.

If `sample_list = [1, 1, 1]`

Then `count_dict = {1: 3}`

For example `11` appears in `sample_list` 2 times then `count_dict[11]` would be equal to `2`.

**UPDATED**

Syntax of assigning value to dict's key in python: `dict[key] = value`

Its like regular lists but in lists you have ready keys which is order of element in list:

```
sample_list = ["a", "b"]
print(sample_list[0])
# >>> a

# changing value
sample_list[0] = "c"

print(sample_list[0])
# >>> c
```

Same with dict but you should define key by yourself

```
# Empty dict
example = {}
# Creating in dict key 99 with value 1
example[99] = 1
print(example[99])
# >>> 1

# Same as example[99] += 1
example[99] = example[99] + 1
print(example[99])
# >>> 2

print(example)
# >>> {99: 2}
# There is only one time with key 99 and value 2

# If i will use key that not in dict:
example[10]
# >>> KeyError: 10
# Because there is no item with key 10
```

Comment: so the computer knows that he have to store this data as a key or the other as a value

Comment: i just did understand that part, ididnt understand how the storage of the keys and the values in the dictionary worked. anyways thanks for your help buddy

Comment: @MohamedOuni syntax of dict: `dict[key] = value`.